# Cost function value in k-means clustering mahout

Tags: algorithm, mahout, k-means

How to compute cost function value in k-means clustering using mahout?

I am undergoing Coursera's class on machine learning. And there it was suggested if we go for random initialization of cluster during *k-means* clustering, to calculate cluster we should do it multiple times with different initial cluster centroids values. Then we should examine the value of cost function to see for which iteration cost incurred is minimum.

Can you please suggest how to calculate cost value in Apache mahout's implementation of k-means clustering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is implementation independent. Simply compute the sum of squared distances from points to their respective centroids. This is your cost function.

Comment: Okay so we have to keep number of clusters as fixed. K-Means will ceases when centroids will be move less than or equal to convergence thershold. So for each execution of K-Means for a initialization at the end we should calculate of sum of squared distances or standard deviation of each training examples from there respective centroids. And sum them up for entire training set. And where ever it is minimum we will reach it to optimum. Is that correct understanding ?

Comment: Without the fixed K, K-means is ill defined, so yes, it has to be fixed. Look at the equation in the wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering , this is exactly your cost function. If you would be able to find the true minimum, it would be "optimal" in the k-means sense (which is just the above function, so it is a tautology), although it is not possible in general (this problem is NP-hard even for K=2 and R^2).

Comment: Thank You So Much !! Since its NP-Hard it will be difficult or impossible to say we are true minimum. Whatever we get is a optimal based on cost incurred. Correct ?

Comment: Not impossible, simply "potentially expensive". You can always give an answer in 2^N time.